# Here document courier imap

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make au automatic script to create a mail account with Courier IMAP. 
I try to use a here document, but the part about the password doesn't work, the user does not have any pass, it means that the lines after the first EOF are not executed

```
userdb $1 set uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/$1 mail=/var/mail/$1 <<EOF
userdbpw -md5 | userdb $1 set systempw
$2                                       
$2                                    
EOF
```

Comment: Provide a minimal, verificable sample input and expected output.

Comment: $1 is the username and $2 is the password that we take as parameters.
If I type this commands, it asks the user to type manually the password, and to confirm it. That's what I want to avoid, then, the user doesn't have to interact at all.

For the moment, with that code, the user is created but without password, so, it doesn't really work

Comment: does this piece of code work when you run it interactively ?

Comment: Yep, if I replace the $1 & $2 by strings and I typpe it interactively, it works !
But If I try to make it automatic with the here documents, the part with the password does not work

Comment: @Michael003 ; give example syntax and equivalent command.  i.e.  Is this supposed to be like typing `userdb john set uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/john mail=/var/mail/john ..............`

Comment: I'm confused by your use of the heredoc.  The way you've structured it doesn't execute the way I think you'd want.

Comment: Well, the example syntax is : 

This is to create the user : 
`userdb USERNAME set uid=5000 home/var/mail/USERNAME mail=/var/mail/USERNAME`
And this is to set a password for the user : 
`userdbpw -md5 | USERNAME set systempw`
After that, it asks the user to choose a password and to confirm it, that's what I want to avoid to make it automatic, by passing the password as second parameter, then my script can set it by himself.

Comment: @Michael003 - You can only make it non-interactive by supplying the password in a non-interactive way.  `set systempw` will prompt for a password if you don't supply it.  See my answer for a possible way to implement as non-interactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
md5pass="$(echo -n "$2" | md5)"
userdb $1 set uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/$1 mail=/var/mail/$1 systempw="$md5pass"
```

... Since you've already opted to make the process non-interactive, hence the password entry is not going to be secure in the event of a `ps` sniff, or `history` in some cases + whatever else is being logged.

Overview:

- `echo -n`: Don't add trailing newline to password
- `md5`: A non-interactive way to get the md5 of password

Note that `userdbpw` reads from stdin.  Providing it a command line argument as input doesn't make it any more secure.

**Alternate ways to get md5:**

A few other ways to get the md5, depending on what utils / packages are available:

- ```
  echo -n pass | openssl dgst -md5
  1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
  ```
- ```
  echo -n pass | md5sum | cut -f1 -d ' '
  1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
  ```
- ```
  echo -n pass | md5
  1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72
  ```

In each of the above;

- ```
  printf "%s" "pass"
  ```

Would also be a suitable replacement for:

- ```
  echo -n "pass"
  ```